# Ruby cannot access a property in database for image tag, though all other tags are working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I'm currently using Ruby to create a web e-commerce app, but suddenly am having an issue with retrieving a property.

I decided to update the image slider of my website with two images instead of one. In order to do so, I added a new property called 'img2_url' to my database of products (also entitled Products), for which there are several existing properties (name, title, year, image_url, etc). I updated the products.controller product_params to include the new property (img2_url), and migrated the change to the database. I uploaded img2_url images for each item in the database under assets/images, and amended the html.erb code for the slider to tag the asset for the second image, right next to the first image, like so:

```
 <% @products.each do |product| %>
<div>
<%= image_tag(product.image_url, :class =>"product_image_thumbnail") %>
<%= image_tag(product.img2_url) %> 
</div>
<%= product.name %>
```

Where product.image_url tags the property for the first image, product.img2_url tags the property for the second image, the new one which I've added, and product.name tags the property for the name of the item.

Unfortunately, what I get back is  that the assets  pipeline successfully retrieves product.image_url, product.name, but not the new property that I just added - product.img2_url. What I get returned from my localhost test site is the following:

```
nil is not a valid asset source
app/views/static_pages/_product.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_static_pages__product_html_erb___2209812928582123295_70176261759380'
app/views/static_pages/landing_page.html.erb:13:in `block in _app_views_static_pages_landing_page_html_erb___3644243706632459022_70176262254540'
app/views/static_pages/landing_page.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_static_pages_landing_page_html_erb___3644243706632459022_70176262254540'
```

I've used ActiveRecord to confirm that I've uploaded the correct corresponding URLs into the database files, that I've uploaded the photos into the assets/images folder, and I've tried inserting the code into different pages. Mind-bogglingly, it works on other pages. I'm beginning to think that maybe the   <% @products.each do |product| %>    tag is the problem, because those pages don't contain that tag. For example, here is code where it works:

```
<h2 class="page-header-form" id="notice"><%= notice %></h2>
<p>
  <strong>Image 2 URL:</strong><br>
  <%= @product.img2_url %><br><br>
  <%= image_tag(@product.img2_url, :class =>"product_image_show") %>
</p>
```

But then again,    <% @products.each do |product| %>    successfully retrieves the data for all other properties, and DOES work, so there must be some way to fix the problem.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you, any help would be SO much appreciated, I've been tearing my hair out.

Comment: the `image_url` or `img2_url` is `nil`, there is no other possibility for this error.

Comment: You can try `product.inspect` inside the loop to get the contents of `product`

Comment: Turns out you're right in that the image_url recorded was actually nil - the column didn't even exist, because I didn't migrate the database correctly. I thought I had migrated it but it turns out that I hadn't committed the change to github before running the migrate command. Thank you!

Comment: Glad you found the answer, good luck with your project!